# TYPO3 forum, where mail template placed

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 7.6.18, and typo3_forum, tell me please, where mail template placed ? I mean when somebody add post to my topic, I get mail. I need this template

Comment: I think you are looking for locallang label `Mail_Subscribe_NewPost_Body` is stored in file : https://github.com/neufeind/typo3-forum/blob/master/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xml#L310

Answer (score 0):

it is without template, it placed in code there 
 /typo3conf/ext/typo3_forum/Classes/Service/Notification/NotificationService.php